# Prove $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k}\frac{1}{(2k+1)(2n-2k+1)}=\frac{2^{\left(4n+1\right)}}{\left(n+1\right)^{2}\binom{2n+2}{n+1}}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

How it can be shown that:

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k}\frac{1}{(2k+1)(2n-2k+1)}=\frac{2^{\left(4n+1\right)}}{\left(n+1\right)^{2}\binom{2n+2}{n+1}}$$

Which is indeed Bruckman’s Formula Version 2.

It seems that there exist a relation between this expression and [Rothe–Hagen identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rothe%E2%80%93Hagen_identity), but I'm not sure.(it's appreciated if someone proves the expression in the most elementary ways, without using hypergeometric functions and integrals)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An *elementary* approach is [WZ-pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilf%E2%80%93Zeilberger_pair). Let
$$F(n,k)=\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k}\binom{2(n+1)}{n+1}\frac{(n+1)^2}{16^n(2k+1)(2(n-k)+1)}$$
Then we have to show that for any $n\geq 0$,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}F(n,k)=1.$$
Verify that 
$$F(n+1,k)-F(n,k)=G(n,k+1)-G(n,k) \tag{1}$$
where
$$G(n,k)=-F(n,k)\cdot \frac{k(2k+1)(3n-2k+4)(2(n-k)+1)^2}{4(2(n-k)+3)(n+1)^3(n-k+1)}.$$
The identity (1) seems terrible but it is not. No summation is involved. Moreover
$$\binom{2(k+1)}{k+1}=2\binom{2k+1}{k}=\binom{2k+1}{k+1}=\frac{2k+1}{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}$$
implies that all the binomial coefficients in (1) can be easily simplified.

It follows that
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}F(n+1,k)-\sum_{k=0}^{n}F(n,k)&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}
(G(n,k+1)-G(n,k))\\
&=G(n,n+1)-G(n,0)=0
\end{align}$$
because the sum on the right is telescopic.
Hence we may conclude that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}F(n,k)=\sum_{k=0}^{0}F(0,k)=F(0,0)=1.$$

Another approach (less *elementary*). Note that the Taylor series of [arcsin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Infinite_series) at $0$ is
$$\arcsin (x)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2k}{k}\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2^{2k}(2k+1)}.$$ 
The given identity is related to the generating function of $(\arcsin (x))^2$ (see [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product)).

Comment: Thanks again, I tried to find a relation between the expression and  Rothe–Hagen identity, but I could not find any good relation, do you have any idea to prove the  expression using Rothe–Hagen identity?

Comment: @user715522 I am afraid that Rothe–Hagen identity is not useful here... Why are you so interested in binomial identities?

Comment: very good question, of course the tools you've used are extremely useful (+1), but often I see that some of binomial identities can be proved just by using the pure binomial relations (which are indeed the tools that can be used as lemmas), at this site [@Markus Scheuer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/132007/markus-scheuer) and  [@Mike Spivey](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/2370/mike-spivey) are the users that always show me in some of the cases there is an elementary solution, and I really want to know if there is any of that here.

Comment: @user715522 Yes, some binomial identities are easier to prove than others. You can find a plenty of Combinatorial Identities on Gould's page: https://math.wvu.edu/~hgould/